# =thread-exited,id="4",group-id="i1" after the message

Tags: c++

I use MinGW g++ compiler for C++, and when executing my program, I get the following message: `{message}=thread-exited,id="4",group-id="i1"`. The message is also in the debug console.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello,World!";
    return 0;
}
```

I didn't try anything as everything was working well. I was just wondering why this happened to try and fix it.

Because someone asked:
[screenshot of debug console + code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3vWg.png)

Comment: in this case i'd recommend you also post a picture of your screen with the error ... i am not sure if that's an actual error, threads do normally exit, this doesn't seem alarming.

Comment: you missed a `\n` at the end, there's nothing else to be concerned about, those debugger messages are normal, just don't start in debug mode if you don't want them.

Comment: As already pointed out, you missed a "new line" at the end of your ``std::cout``. Add ``<< std::endl`` at the end of the line, right before the ``;``. Besides that though, the message you are seeing is likely not a bug nor issue but something normal and expected due to the fact that you are running in debug mode. Your IDE could also be behind this, for, again, debugging purposes.